# Save selected part of web page as text file using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a web page with few tabs. All tabs have same data but in different format. The page has a copy to clipboard feature which copies the contents of the active tab to clipboard. Similarly we need to have a save as text file option which copies contents of the active tab alone by prompting use for selecting a location and then ssving it.
I checked a few alternatives like use of execcommand, but not sure whats best way to do the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish this by posting the contents to a server page which would basically echo the contents back in such a way as to provoke the browser into launching a "what do you want to do with this?" dialog where one option is "Save to disk." If there's a way to get the client to go straight to the "Save to disk" option, all the better.

I've found that different browsers deal with this in different ways - some look at the extension of the server page, and some at the HTTP content-type.

For example, I had a page, call it server.cgi, which would produce a zip file and I think IE defaulted the file name in the "Save As" dialog to server.cgi. By changing the server file to server.zip, the prompt did the right thing. I think Firefox responded to the content-type header.